# Origin of "no such thing" idiomatic phrase

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

The risk of asking this question could be like asking the question

> What is the origin of the phrase "I love you", or "I need a shower", etc

which grew out of spontaneous language use.

Anyway, I am willing to take that risk because I have a strong feeling that its origins could be traced to a few or a singular event.

Examples of usage:

- There is no such thing as a free lunch.
- There is no such thing as Truth.
- There is no such thing as real democracy.
- There is no such thing as blah .. blah ...

Comment: To demonstrate the universality of the phrase ... I was in the far-east many years ago and a vendor yelled to a passer-by "$30 for the bag". Passer-by shakes his head. "OK $29." After lowering a couple more rungs, the vendor finally says to the smiling man, "OK, I lose money, $25." The passer-by then forwards himself closer to the vendor to respond with, "There is no such thing as selling me your bag to lose money." To which the vendor responded, "Because you are my very special customer today."

Comment: Another interesting phrase is "to be a thing", like in "since when is it a thing" or "it's not even a thing!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm curious as to how else you would phrase "no such thing", so that it appears to you a strange enough construction as to make speaking of it's origin worth considering? It is the word *no* used in a normal manner, followed by the word *such* used in a normal manner, followed by the word *thing* used in a normal manner.

*Such* followed by *thing* we have from Old English "Exodus", which is believed compiled around 930-960 and composed earlier:

> Hig worhton óðer swilc þing þurh hira drýcræft and þurh Egiptisce galdru fecērunt etiam ipsi per incantātiōnes Ægyptiacas et arcāna quædam simĭlĭter

*No* followed by *such* depends on when you consider *nan* with the final consonant dropped to stop being *none* and start being *no*. The following is earlier than that, from Ælfric's "The Homilies of the Anglo-Saxon Church", and at some point in the next couple of hundred years, *na* would have been used even if what followed began with a vowel, and this would be closer to *no* than to *none*.

> na swilc word swa menn sprecadh, ac he is dhaes Faeder Wisdom, and word bidh wisdomes geswutelung. Thaet Word is Aelmihtig God, Sunu mid his Faeder.

While I can't find at *na swilc þing* or *na swylc þing* or similar, I think it suffices to say that by the time *no* and *none* were separate words in our language (though their senses still overlap so that some uses of "no such things" could be "none such thing", albeit that might sound a bit archaic).

If we don't care about when *no* began to be separate to *none*, then we can find "Nán swylc" in the 8th Century "Cynewulf's Christ".

"No such thing" is just normal English words used normally, rather than an idiom as such.

Comment: I found two such instances in Jane Eyre - "no such thing". While "no such things" occurs only once. And "no such xxx" occur a total of 5 times. But I could not find "no such thing" in any of Shakespeare's plays,

Comment: I can't find "I like apples" in Shakespare too, but I've no doubt he would have understood it had I said it to him.

Comment: Jon is correct. The phrase "no such thing" really is just plain English.

Comment: Not part of OP's question, but for me it's the "as" that makes the expression interesting. As far as I know, we don't use "as" as a conjunction like this anywhere else in English. We often use it as a comparative conjunction (e.g., "she's as wise as an owl") but where else is "as" used like this? I think it is an idiomatic phrase if you include the "as."

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the phrase does appear in Shakespeare.  In "Macbeth" during the famous speech "is this a dagger I see before me."  I would be willing to bet that this might be the first usage of the phrase "there's no such thing."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We discourage users to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.